# i am getting error while adding coupon value in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

invalid form key while adding discount coupon value in shopping cart in magento 2.3 i have tried increasing max_input_vars to 30000 but no luck can anyone help us in fixing this issue [image]

Comment: are you in local ?

Comment: no live site....